# Given the parity of a function, how can I find the value of a parameter?

Tags: parametric-functions

Given that the function g [x] is an even function

```
g[x_] := (x + a) Log[(2 x - 1)/(2 x + 1)]
```

How to find the value of parameter a?

I tried the following method but couldn't solve it

```
g[x_] := (x + a) Log[(2 x - 1)/(2 x + 1)]
ForAll[x, x < -(1/2) || x > 1/2, g[-x] == g[x]]
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g[a_, x_] := (x + a) Log[(2 x - 1)/(2 x + 1)]

Solve[g[a, x] == g[a, -x], a, Reals][[1]] // Simplify

(* {a -> ConditionalExpression[0, x > 1/2 || x < -(1/2)]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
Assuming[x > 1/2 || x < -1/2,
 g[0, x] == g[0, -x] // Simplify]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to verify that for `a==0` the function `g[x_] := (x + a) Log[(2 x - 1)/(2 x + 1)]` is even. There is no other value of `a` with such a property as

```
FindInstance[ ForAll[a, a != 0,  x < -(1/2) ||   x > 1/2 && (a + x) Log[(-1 + 2 x)/(
   1 + 2 x)] != (a - x) Log[(-1 - 2 x)/(1 - 2 x)]], x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> -75}}`

shows.